# AngularJS - How create a form with specific format?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm newbie in AngularJS and I'm working on ACTIVITI.

I need to create a form in a specific format. Every response must be in the form of:

```
{
    "taskId" : "5",
    "properties" : [
        {
            "id" : "room",
            "value" : "normal"
        }
    ]
}
```

The user input some text in the form, and the attribute "value" need to be equal to the user input.

How to reach this in AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you bind your input with the ng-model directive to your value:

controller:

```
$scope.toto = {
  "taskId" : "5",
  "properties" : [
    {
      "id" : "room",
      "value" : "normal"
    }
  ]
}
```

.html:

```
<input ng-model="toto.properties[0].value">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
<input ng-model="formInfo.taskId">
<input ng-model="formInfo.properties.id">
<input ng-model="formInfo.properties.value">
```

controller:

```
console.log($scope.formInfo.taskId);
console.log($scope.formInfo.properties.id);
console.log($scope.formInfo.properties.value);
```